# How to make horizontal flatlist with 2 rows but the first item should be in one row(full height) and other in half?

Tags: react-native, flatlist

I've a flatlist of photos but want to show like below image.

[image]

I want to show first item like above image as big box and other images as other half box as seen as in above image.

```
<FlatList
   data={photos}
   numColumns={Math.ceil(photos.length/2)}
   keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
   renderItem={({item, index}) => {
      return (
          <Image 
            source={item.image} 
            style={{ 
               margin: 5, 
               width: index === 0 ? 100 : 50, 
               height: index === 0 ? 100 : 50, 
               borderRadius: 10
            }} 
         />
      )
   }}
/>
```

Comment: I am not sure how this react question, but it doable with css grid

Comment: wait? so this is a vertical scroll with just the first box to be big?, how does the rest of the scroll looks like

Comment: @GauravRoy No, this is horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps. since in horizontal numOfColums isnt supported, you need to modify your data and add conditions in renderItem.
This code is exactly what @andrew developed . all credits to him
Do let me know in case of any doubts
:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native';
export default class Screen1 extends React.Component {

  state = {
    data: [
      { text: 'one' },
      { item1: { text: 'two' }, item2: { text: 'three' } },
      { item1: { text: 'four' }, item2: { text: 'five' } },
      { item1: { text: 'six' }},
    ]
  }

  renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.bigSquare}>
          <Text>{item.text}</Text>
        </View>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <View>
          <View style={styles.smallSquare}>
            <Text>{item.item1.text}</Text>
          </View>
          {item.item2 && <View style={[styles.smallSquare, {backgroundColor: 'red'}]}>
            <Text>{item.item2.text}</Text>
          </View>}
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

  keyExtractor = (item, index) => `${index}`;

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList 
          horizontal={true}
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  bigSquare: {
    height: 220, 
    width: 220, 
    margin: 10, 
    backgroundColor: 'yellow', 
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  smallSquare: {
    height: 100, 
    width: 100, 
    margin: 10, 
    backgroundColor: 'green', 
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
```

PFA link for the same [Snack expo](https://snack.expo.dev/YWZESymfM)